# Unable to call the nested function with timer until met condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have 2 methods that call some APIs:

1. `getData(param)`.
2. `getAnotherData(resp from get data)`.

The below method calls the first method:

```js
this.service.getData(param).subscribe(res => {
    this.variable = res;

    // here based on the first response i will call the second api 

    this.service.getAnotherData(this.variable['data']).subscribe(res2 =>  

    // Here, I will get a response which will be either "started"
    // or not "started". If it's not "started", then I have to call
    // this API until I get "started" for up to 1 minute.
)})
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to avoid nested subscriptions. Instead try to use higher order mapping operators like `switchMap`.
2. You could use RxJS `repeat` and `takeWhile` operators to subscribe again to an observable until it satisfies a condition.

Try the following

```js
this.service.getData(param).pipe(
  switchMap(res => 
    this.service.getAnotherData(res['data']).pipe(
      repeat(),
      takeWhile(res => res === 'started')      // poll `getAnotherData()` until response is 'started'
    )
  )
).subscribe(
  res => { },
  err => { }
);
```

Comment: ok but here i have another scenario  polling `getAnotherData()` until response is 'started'  and if has to poll upto max 1 min only and and can we also able to cancel this timer or call via a button  >

Comment: for calling timer can we use timeout operator?

Comment: @Madpop: `timeout` wouldn't help. `timeout` will only emit an error when there is _no_ emission. Here the observable would be emitting continuously and the `timeout`'s timer will get reset on every emission.

Comment: ok but how can we do that then if the condition is not met then it has to call the api upto 1 min until the condition is met

Comment: and in the subscribe which method response will come bcoz if condition met i have to call a method

Comment: @Madpop: I'm too not quite sure how to conditionally timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider below approach using `timer` operator

```
  private readonly _stop = new Subject<void>();
  private readonly _start = new Subject<void>();
  trialTime = 60 * 1000;
  trialInterval = 500;
  timer$ = timer(0, this.trialInterval).pipe(
    takeUntil(this._stop),
    takeWhile( i => (this.trialTime / this.trialInterval) > i),
    repeatWhen(() => this._start),
  );
  start(): void { this._start.next();}
  stop(): void { this._stop.next();}

  responses = [];

  ngOnInit()  {
    const param = 1;
    this.timer$.pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.service.getData(param)),
      switchMap(res => this.service.getAnotherData(res.data)),
      tap(res => this.responses.push(res)),
      tap(res => { if (res === 'started') { this.stop(); }}),
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

The above approach will run for 60s and if not started, this will automatically stop.

A user can also manually stop and start the observable

[See Below link on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-otvkaq)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you and had to do something similar with vanilla JS, I would use this approach:

```
1. Subscribe to `getData` function call result
2. In the scope of subscription handler:
  2.1 Add a new method to indicate if 1 minute has elapsed with initial value to `false`
  2.2 Use `setTimeout` to callback a function and update flag after a minute to `true`
  2.3 Create inline function which would call `getAnotherData` method and subscribe to it's result and within its subscription scope
    2.3.1 If result is started, clear timeout so that timeout event handler will be cleared
    2.3.2 If one minute is not elapsed, call inline function again
  2.4 call inline function
```

something like:

```
this.service.getData(param).subscribe(res => {
    this.variable = res;
    const minuteElapsed = false;

    // based on the first response
    const timeoutHandler = setTimeout(
        () => { minuteElapsed = true; },
        60000
    );
    const fetchAnotherData = () => {
        this.service.getAnotherData(this.variable['data']).subscribe(res2 =>  
            if (res === 'started') {
                clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); // clean up
                // do stuff!
            } else if (!minuteElapsed) {
                fetchAnotherData(); // calling again!
            }
        });
    };
    fetchAnotherData(); // call inline function
})
```

Comment: @madpop did you get a chance to take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Like what was mentioned in the other answers, avoid nested subscriptions whenever possible. I'd approach this with rxjs `expand` operator, which we will use to re-run the second API-request until your desired result is received.

`expand` will pass-through the observed value from the API request and, depending on a condition, you can have it either stop additional processing or just repeat the call.

We can then use `takeUntil` to implement a timeout to the request. It might look something like this (I'm borrowing the scaffolding from another answer):

```
this.service.getData(param).pipe(
  switchMap(res => 
    this.service.getAnotherData(res['data']).pipe(
      expand((result) => result === 'finished' ? EMPTY : this.service.getAnotherData(res['data']).pipe(delay(500))),
      takeUntil(timer(60000).pipe(
        // Here, you can react to the timeout
        tap(() => console.log('Timeout occurred'))
      )),
    )
  )
).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    /**
      Do whatever you want with the result, you need to check again for 'finished',
      since everything is passed through
     */
  }
  err => { }
);
```

Have a play with it here: https://retry-api.stackblitz.io

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: usage of toPromise will be depreciated, see comments on this answer**

---

if your function containing the calls is `async` you could use `await` to wait for the result ***in this particular case***.

```js
  const res = await this.service.getData(param).toPromise();
  this.variable = res;
  
  let anotherData;
  while (anotherData !== 'started') {
    anotherData = await this.service.getAnotherData(this.variable['data']).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `toPromise()` method. It is [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 and out in RxJS 8.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that. It seems though we can use `await lastValueFrom(this.service.getAnotherData(this.variable['data']))` in future?